# RxSwift: Set initial value for UIPickerView

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I'm trying to set the initial value for UIPickerView.

Here, an example of my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Observable.just([1, 2, 3])
        .bind(to: pickerView.rx.itemTitles) { _, item in
            return "\(item)"
        }
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)

    pickerView.rx.modelSelected(Int.self)
        .subscribe(onNext: { models in
            print("models selected 1: \(models)")
        })
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

I don't know how I can make a two-way binding with my ViewModel or just set the initial value.

Any ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, using UIPickerView own method is fine;

> mPicker.selectRow(defaultRowIndex, inComponent: 0, animated: false)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the @halley-wang's answer, I found a solution in the RxSwift repo: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/Tests/RxCocoaTests/UIPickerView%2BRxTests.swift#L169-L170

So, here my code:

```
let row = 42 // Default row
pickerView.selectRow(row, inComponent: 0, animated: false)
pickerView.delegate?.pickerView!(pickerView,
                                 didSelectRow: row,
                                 inComponent: 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a variable in viewmodel of type : Variable. In your viewcontroller make that variable observable and bind to pickerview. If you change the value of variable it will automatically be reflected in pickerview.

Sample code snippet could be:

```
//viewmodel file: --------------
var dataSourceArray: Variable<[String]> = Variable([])
//somewhere after receiving data: add to data source
dataSourceArray.value.append(YOUR_NEW_DATA)

////// viewcontroller file----------------
self.viewModel.dataSourceArray.asObservable().bind(to: pickerView.rx.itemTitles) { _, item in
        return "\(item)"
    }
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Kindly ignore few of syntax if any. Let me know for any further help.

Comment: I would not suggest using a `Variable` for this at all, as its deprecated.

Comment: @ShaiMishali can you suggest how can it be replaced with BehaviorRelay? I m kinda novice in RxSwift for this change. Suggestions are appreciated :)